# Browsing Server Directory with javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use Javascript to list all the files contained in a subfolder?

I have a bunch of images that need to be linked too, but I would like it to be dynamic because the list will be changing a lot.

Thankyou!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use Javascript to list all the files contained in a subfolder?

No. You would usually set up a simple server side script that does the listing (e.g. using PHP's [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)), and output a JSON array, for example.

Comment: It depends. If the oparating system from server is Windows, you can use Jscript. JScript is a "extension" of Javascript.

Comment: @reporter I don't see how - JScript running on the client's browser can not do anything on server side, either

Comment: so then, how would i pass the file name array from php to javascript? can the two even be used together?

Comment: @Alex you could use Ajax to make a call to a PHP script that outputs JSON. Or you could do a `<script src='myfile.php'>` and have `myfile.php` output a JSON array

Comment: @Pekka If you use an IIS you the option to use vbscript or jscript language by default. Create an .asp file (asp-classic) and read your directory. On client side, if you want to read a folder structure either you have to install an IIS or create a WSH Script that uses JScript as language. If you want use just the general javascript you can't do it (but I think you can do that with new version of javascript (Keyword: HTML5). But I'm not sure about this)

Comment: @reporter fair enough, but I 'm fairly sure the OP referred to client-side JS specifically. What you say is a fine server-side solution, though.

Comment: @pekka & reporter: for microsoft servers (server side) using node.js is another option.