# Have the HTML File Selector browse server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, server

I am trying to get the `HTML` file selector `<input type="file">` to browse files that are on my server, instead of local. I know `JS` is client side, and I tried researching various implementations but no one seems to have something on this. I would prefer an implementation that doesn't require downloading any external application (I already have `jQuery` and `ajax`).

edit: I don't know why I'm getting down voted! I'm not trying to get Javascript to list files I feed from the server, I'm trying to explore the servers files and directories like I was physically on it from the "file" api.

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331244/browsing-server-directory-with-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browsing Server Directory with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331244/browsing-server-directory-with-javascript)

Comment: Use [`Node.js`](https://nodejs.org/en/) for things like that. It lets you execute `JavaScript` as a back-end.

Comment: Fortunately it's not possible with JavaScript in client. You should list the files with some code in server side. From JS you could call that code with ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the `HTML` file-selector `<input type="file">` to browse files that are on your server.

However, you can set up a workaround using a little server-side programming. Create an API route on the server that sends the structure of files that are on your server in response (maybe in the form of a JSON object or an array) and use that to show the file structure to the user.